# C/C++: Float comparison speed

Tags: c++, c, performance, comparison, floating-point

I am checking to make sure a float is not zero. It is impossible for the float to become negative. So is it faster to do this `float != 0.0f` or this `float > 0.0f`?

Thanks.

Edit: Yes, I know this is micro-optimisation. But this is going to be called every time through my game loop, and I would like to know anyway.

Comment: floats can be negative.  They can also be flaky around zero.

Comment: the word micro-optimisiation springs to mind!

Comment: The difference, if there is one, is likely to be so incredibly small that you would never, ever notice the difference. Have you profiled your code and found that this particular comparison is a performance bottleneck? The difference, if there is one, is also quite likely to be architecture- and CPU-specific. Are you sure that if the value is zero that it will be _exactly_ zero? Remember that floating point computations are usually inexact.  Unless you explicitly set `f = 0.0f;`, you need to account for computational error.

Comment: @uncle yes, floats can be negative. it is in my case that it can't.

Comment: @Jay: If they can be zero then there is good chance they can be negative. Even when the math says they should be equal to 0 the reality of floating point arithmetic means that it can be very close to zero but on the negative side.

Comment: @Jay: As a game developer, I'm going to tell you that if you cannot figure out how to determine which version to use, then your game is not high-performance enough to *need* to know. **Always write the code that's cleanest.** Never ever write the code that's "fastest", because until you have a *clean, working* program, it doesn't matter. You want fast? `int main() {}`. I guarantee that's faster than anything you can write. "But it doesn't do anything!" Neither does broken code that was written to be fast instead of correct.

Comment: @GMan: Depending on platform, there can be many "microoptimizations like this that don't really matters" that actually turn out to make a difference. Better to know about them before you write the game than at the end, where you find the frame rate is too low and maybe need to apply micro-optimizations afterwards.

Comment: @kotlinski: I agree there can be many small optimizations, some platform-dependent, that can make a difference. That said, I disagree that they are the most important thing anytime before the end of the products lifetime, or before it's noticeable. It's extremely easy to optimize clean code with platform-specific chunks, but it's not hard to extend and manage a messy program built "for speed" rather than "for correctness". And as for a specific persons needs, I highly doubt someone who doesn't know where to look for what to do (profiler/articles/etc.) is in a position to need them.

Comment: @GMan Part of the reason I asked this question was because I wasn't sure which was cleaner/clearer, so I thought I might choose based on speed.

Comment: @Jay In short term: `hare.speed > turtle.speed`. But: `turtle.speed=time` and `hare.speed=1.0/time`

Comment: @Jay You know, that story about [Hare vs Tortoise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tortoise_and_the_Hare)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider, for entertainment purposes only:

Only 2 floating point values compare equal to `0f`: zero and negative zero, and they differ only at 1 bit. So circuitry/software emulation that tests whether the 31 non-sign bits are clear will do it.

The comparison `>0f` is slightly more complicated, since negative numbers and 0 result in false, positive numbers result in true, but NaNs (of both signs) also result in false, so it's slightly more than just checking the sign bit.

Depending on the floating point mode, either operation could cause a super-precise result in a floating point register to be rounded to 32 bit before comparison, so the score's even there.

If there was a difference at all, I'd sort of expect `!=` to be faster, but I wouldn't really expect there to be a difference and I wouldn't be very surprised to be wrong on some particular implementation.

I assume that your proof that the value cannot be negative is not subject to floating point errors. For example, calculations along the lines of `1/2.0 - 1/3.0 - 1/6.0` or `0.4 - 0.2 - 0.2` can result in either positive or negative values if the errors happen to accumulate rather than cancelling, so presumably nothing like that is going on. About only real use of a floating-point test for equality with 0, is to test whether you have assigned a literal `0` to it. Or the result of some other calculation guaranteed to have result `0` in `float`, but that can be tricksy.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph, the float is lowered by being repeatedly multiplied by a less-than-one value.

Comment: On hardware level the checks could be performed in parallel, so both checks would take the same amount of time. And considering that a branch missprediction is much more expensive, there will be no difference in speed.

Comment: @ruslik: *could* be performed in parallel, or are guaranteed to be performed in parallel? Hence, *there will be no difference in speed*, or *there is very likely to be no difference in speed*? Put another way, what odds would you offer that nobody can present a C implementation in which there is a difference in speed, one way or the other? Would you feel confident offering 1000:1? My money would be on something with software float on a relatively simple CPU such as an early series ARM, as the most likely candidate for a difference.

Answer (score 8):

There is not likely to be a detectable difference in performance.

Comment: and `float > 0.0f`, or better `float > EPSION` is safer.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to give a clear cut answer without knowing your platform and compiler. The C standard does not define how floats are implemented.

On some platforms, yes, on other platforms, no.

If in doubt, measure.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, `f != 0.0f` will sometimes return true when you think it should be false.

To check whether a float number is non-zero, you should do `Math.abs(f) > EPSILON`, where `EPSILON` is the error you can tolerate.

Performance shouldn't be a big issue in this comparison.

Comment: FYI, he said the number is always >= 0 so you don't need the abs.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly the sort of micro-optimization you shouldn't do until you have quantitative data showing that it's a problem. If you can prove it's a problem, you should figure out how to make your compiler show the machine instructions it's generating, then take that info and go to the data book for the processor you are using, and look up the number of clock cycles required for alternative implementations of the same logic. Then you should measure again to make sure you are seeing the benefits, if any.

If you don't have any data showing that's it's a performance problem stick with the implementation that most clearly and simply presents the logic of what you are trying to do.